# Possible Android Thread Bug - Custom Listener

Tags: android, multithreading, listener

please see the codes:

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
TestClass tc = new TestClass();
tc.Test(new TestListener() {
    public void onSuccess() {
             //success do something
        }

        public void onFail() {
            //fail do something
        }
    });
}
```

TestClass:

```
public class TestClass {

    private static final int MSG_SUCCESS = 1;
    private static final int MSG_FAIL = 0;

    private TestListener listener = null;

    public void Test(TestListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        Log.d("test", "=======" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("MyThread");
        ht.start();

        Thread thread = new Thread(mRunnable);
        thread.run();
    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_SUCCESS:
                Log.d("test", "on success");
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onSuccess();
                }
                break;
            case MSG_FAIL:
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onFail();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    };

    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("test", "=======" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            try {
                Log.d("test", "start sleep");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("test", "sleep end");
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_SUCCESS).sendToTarget();
        }

    };
}
```

TestListener:

```
public interface TestListener {

    public void onSuccess();
    public void onFail();

}
```

print log:

```
07-30 15:15:03.565: D/test(2202): =======1
07-30 15:15:03.565: D/test(2202): =======1
```

Slaver Thread have no effect？？

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
thread.run();
```

That's running the `Runnable` code *synchronously*, in the existing thread. You meant:

```
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you will have to show() your Toast msgs:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onsuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and you want to start() your thread:

```
thread.start();
```